# NHibernate Delete with date arithmatic using HQL

Tags: date, datetime, nhibernate, hql

I've looked around and can't find too much. But is it possible to do something like this using HQL in nHibernate:

Session.CreateQuery(@"DELETE FROM MyObject mo
                       WHERE (mo.AlteredDate + mo.ExpiryDetails.ExpiryTimestamp) < :pNow")
                    .SetDateTime("pNow", DateTime.Now);

So basically I want to delete all MyObjects from the database where the last time the object was altered (mo.AlteredDate  - a DateTime) plus an amount of time such as 2 days and 5 hours (ExpiryDetails.ExpiryTimestamp) is less than now.

Or is it best to retrieve the objects and do the caculation in code using the .NET framework?

Answer (score 2):

Super late to answer, but I did something like this & it works:

```
IQuery query = Session.CreateQuery("select x from OBJECT x where x.DateTimeForCompare > :dateTimeForCompare2");

query.SetDateTime("dateTimeForCompare2", DateTime.Today);

IList<OBJECT> xx = query.List<OBJECT>();
```